# How to provide an API key for ssl-vp.com in a Google Sheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, api-key

I'm trying to get JSON data from a URL and insert the data in the sheets of Google Sheets. The problem is when I try to get the data this response me that error:

> Error in the request for the returned code 401 of https://ssl-vp.com/rest/v1/Campaigns/1236223656534991/Recipients?by=ExternalId&page=1&itemsPerPage=500. Truncated server response: Unauthorized Cannot get campaign contacts (use the muteHttpExceptions option to examine the entire response) (line 15, file "Código")

I try to insert the API KEY in the URL but the response is the same error

```json
function myFunction(){
var url = "https://ssl-vp.com/rest/v1/Campaigns/1236223656534991/Recipients?by=ExternalId&page=1&itemsPerPage=500";
var apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var header={
    "headers":{
         "X-API-KEY":apiKey
    }
  };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,header);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ssl-vp.com's API docs](https://ssl-vp.com/rest/), this service expects the API key in the `Authorization` header like so:

```
Authorization: Bearer <API_KEY>
```

Change your code to:

```
var header = {
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey
  }
};
```

Comment: thank, is working... but where you find this doc i dont find it

Comment: It's not mentioned explicitly but you can learn this from testing the requests. 1) Paste the API key into the "Token" field on the left. 2) Open the browser dev tools > Network tab. 3) Try any operation. 4) Examine the request headers on the Network tab in dev tools - you will see that the key is sent in the `Authorization` header.